# How to backup Google Storage buckets?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I need to backup our Google Storage buckets. Versioning is not enough. 
I was thinking about:

- **backup to s3** - is there an automated bucket sync from GS->S3 or out-of-the-box solution for scheduled transfers between buckets?
- **backup to another GS bucket** - in the same gc project, a coldline bucket "replica" with read-only privs to most users and some automated process to replicate/sync the data?
- any other ideas?

thanks:)

Comment: Google cloud does not support any inbuilt service to use for this purpose, so best you can do is run `gsutil rsync` cron job from some machine to trigger this as suggested by @Mike. Also, I would recommend doing the backup on GS bucket if you have a large amount of data, as GS bucket to GS bucket is very fast.

Comment: thanks @YogeshPatil. So I guess the best would be sync it with cron to bucket in different geolocation? Any idea if there is a fee for the traffic between two different coldline/nearline geolocations?

Comment: Wait I think this Google cloud transfer service is an answer to your problem. https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/. Let me know if it is one which solves your purpose, I will update the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use gsutil rsync to do this:

```
gsutil -m rsync -rd gs://your-bucket s3://your-bucket
```

(similarly for syncing between GCS buckets).

You would need to set up a cron job or something similar to cause this to run periodically.

Comment: I'm looking for this "as a service".

Comment: I am receiving the following error when trying to do this

`
Caught non-retryable exception while listing s3://my-s3-bucket/: AccessDeniedException: 403 InvalidAccessKeyId
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>{ACCESS_KEY}</AWSAccessKeyId><RequestId>{REQUEST_ID}</RequestId><HostId>{HOST_ID}</HostId></Error>
CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync
`

Comment: Posted another question here instead - https://stackoverflow.com/q/71471638/1079901

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a comment, [GCS Transfer](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/transfer) is what you are looking for, at least for the part: "backup to another GS bucket".

From the doc:

> Transfer data to your Cloud Storage buckets from Amazon Simple Storage
>   Service (S3), HTTP/HTTPS servers, or other buckets. You can schedule
>   one-time or daily transfers, and you can filter files based on name
>   prefix and when they were changed.

Comment: Hi, would it be enough just to backup to another bucket in gcs or necessary to also backup to aws?

Comment: It depends on your use case, but I think backup to another bucket is enough, you can also create that other bucket in another region/zone if that feels safer for you.