# gsutil rsync with s3 buckets gives InvalidAccessKeyId error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to copy all the data from an AWS S3 bucket to a GCS bucket. Acc. to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47289296/1079901) `rsync` command should have been able to do that. But I am receiving the following error when trying to do that

```
Caught non-retryable exception while listing s3://my-s3-source/: AccessDeniedException: 403 InvalidAccessKeyId
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>{REDACTED}</AWSAccessKeyId><RequestId>{REDACTED}</RequestId><HostId>{REDACTED}</HostId></Error>
CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync
```

This is the command I am trying to run

```
gsutil -m rsync -r s3://my-s3-source gs://my-gcs-destination
```

I have the AWS CLI installed which is working fine with the same AccessKeyId and listing buckets as well as objects in the bucket.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`gsutil` can work with both Google Storage and S3.

`gsutil rsync -d -r s3://my-aws-bucket gs://example-bucket`

You just need to configure it with both - Google and your AWS S3 credentials. For GCP you need to add the [Amazon S3 credentials to   `~/.aws/credentials`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability#gsutil_command_line) or you can also store your AWS [credentials in the .boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025324/google-cloud-using-gsutil-to-download-data-from-aws-s3-to-gcs) configuration file for gsutil. However, when you're accessing an Amazon S3 bucket with gsutil, the Boto library uses your `~/.aws/credentials` file to override other credentials, such as any that are stored in `~/.boto`.

**=== 1st update ===**

Also make sure you have to make sure you have the correct IAM permissions on the GCP side and the correct AWS IAM credentials. Also depending if you have a prior version of Migrate for Compute Engine [(formerly Velostrata)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025324/google-cloud-using-gsutil-to-download-data-from-aws-s3-to-gcs) use this documentation and make sure you set up the VPN, IAM credentials and AWS network. If you are using the [current version (5.0)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability#gsutil_command_line), use the following documentation to check everything is configured correctly.

Comment: I have my credentials stored in the env vars instead and it works with the AWS CLI. gsutil is picking up the credentials since it's printing the correct accessKeyId. So I think it's not that. But I'll put it in the boto file too and see if that works

Comment: Added some iseful information to the answer

Comment: Were you able to test if it works?